# How to create location map in nagios server?

Tags: networking, server, nagios3

I already complete the installation and configuring process in Nagios server on Ubuntu. Now, I want to create location map or network map in my own nagios server. How I can do it? Please given this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status map in nagos is generated automatically. You have to set a parent host for each host in the `define host` statement of the host. See an example:

```
define host{
        use             generic-host          
        host_name       host
        address         1.2.3.4
        parents         other-host
}
```

It also accepts multiple parents. But **notice**: there must be also a `define host` statement for the parent host.

Comment: It is possible to define co-ordinates in host definitions. That's what OP is asking about, I think.

Comment: @muru you can define custom variables, but if you want real maps like this http://sysadmins.ru/files/nagvis_819.gif you need nagvis.

Comment: No need for custom variables. Look at `2d_coords` and `3d_coords` in http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#host - they aren't real maps like nagvis, but they are built-in options.